# Using maven archetype template variables inside javascript files

Tags: javascript, java, maven, webpack, maven-archetype

I'm creating a Maven archetype that includes a javascript file. I would like to use the `${package}` and `${artifactId}` template variables inside my javascript file. Is this possible?

When I then generate a project from the archetype, the javascript file still includes the `${package}` rather than the value of `package`.

Here is the relevant part of my archetype-metadata.xml

```
<fileSets>
  <fileSet encoding="UTF-8">
        <directory></directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.json</include>
            <include>**/*.js</include>
            <include>**/*.lock</include>
            <include>.eslintignore</include>
            <include>.gitignore</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `filtered` to `true` on the fileSet.